# CVE-2017-5753 bounds check bypass aka the huge bug everybody is talking about

Tags: c, performance, security, intel

While reading project zero's explanations about  CVE-2017-5753 (see here https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.fr/2018/01/reading-privileged-memory-with-side.html?m=1) I stumbled over this assertion:

By measuring the time required to load arr2->data[0x200] and arr2->data[0x300], an attacker can then determine whether the value of index2 during speculative execution was 0x200 or 0x300

AFAIK access time to arrays does not depend on the offset you're looking at, so how is it possible to measure a different loading time here ?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to create a simple answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099475/101087)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory latency depends on cache hit/miss.  Read
[What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper.

Or just read the Meltdown attack paper (https://meltdownattack.com/meltdown.pdf) which explains all of this as background for how the attack works, including the `clflush`+Read side-channel to convert microarchitectural state (what's cached) into architectural state (a register value in the unprivileged code you're running).

It's a pretty good paper, but they could be more clear that it depends on Intel CPUs treating kernel-only page mappings as valid for speculative execution of user-space code.  There would be no vulnerability if mappings that you don't have privilege to read from internally acted the same as unmapped pages.  Presumably this is the case on AMD, and that's why AMD CPUs are microarchitecturally immune to this attack.  But Intel CPUs apparently use the TLB hit and continue speculative execution until the faulting load tries to retire.

It's linked from the front page of https://meltdownattack.com/.

Maybe you didn't see it if you were only looking at the other vulnerability, not Meltdown.  But the side-channel is the same.

Comment: Thanks actually the answer is even simpler but I read it too fast, as either  arr2->data[0x200] or arr2->data[0x300] will remain in L1 cache after the speculative execution path there will obviously be a difference in access time between the two offsets. It was clearly written just before what I cut and pasted here... Anyway thanks for the links for further reading, they seem to be quite interesting.